# Bound on Commutator of Unitary Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, operator-theory

This is an exercise from Terry Tao's blog.

If $U$ and $V$ are unitary $n \times n$ matrices, show that the commutator $[U,V] := UVU^{-1} V^{-1}$ obeys the inequality
$$
\|[U,V]-I\|_{op} \leq 2 \|U-I\|_{op} \|V - I \|_{op}
$$

We are provided the hint: (first control $\|UV - VU\|_{op}$.)

Comment: What norm is "op"?

Comment: It signifies the operator norm.

Comment: Also provide a link when referring to a blog post